Phoenix server not accessible from other devices
I've a phoenix liveview app to try Liveview native which I want to connect to from my ipad.
I'm on linux so I allowed the access to the port 4000 with ufw, but the connection still failed in my ipad (i used lvn go app).
The error i got in lvn go when I tried to connect :
initialFetchError(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeK
ey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x30177dbf0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, ipv6, dns, uses wifi, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <04A35415-75B1-4226-9096-BFB3FE59C8E7>.<9>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
  "LocalDataTask <04A35415-75B1-4226-9096-BFB3FE59C8E7>.<9>"
 ), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.140:4000/?_interface%5Btarget%5D=ipados&_interface%5Bbundle_id%5D=com.dockyard.LiveViewNativeGo&_interface%5Bapp_version%5D=0.3.1&_interface%5Bos%5D=iOS&_interface%5Bi18n%5D%5Btime_zone%5D=Europe/Paris&_interface%5Bos_version%5D=17.7.1&_interface%5Bapp_build%5D=1&_interface%5Bl10n%5D%5Blocale%5D=en_FR&_format=swiftui, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.140:4000/?_interface%5Btarget%5D=ipados&_interface%5Bbundle_id%5D=com.dockyard.LiveViewNativeGo&_interface%5Bapp_version%5D=0.3.1&_interface%5Bos%5D=iOS&_interface%5Bi18n%5D%5Btime_zone%5D=Europe/Paris&_interface%5Bos_version%5D=17.7.1&_interface%5Bapp_build%5D=1&_interface%5Bl10n%5D%5Blocale%5D=en_FR&_format=swiftui, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1})


You might want to include the code  (in text form) that you are using that generates that error so someone can attempt to recreate to find a solution for you.

I haven't tried LiveView native, but with regular Phoenix one thing to check is this section of config/dev.exs that is generated by mix phx.new:
config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  # Binding to loopback ipv4 address prevents access from other machines.
  # Change to `ip: {0, 0, 0, 0}` to allow access from other machines.
  http: [ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, port: 4000],

For me it worked to change that last line to this:
  http: [ip: {0, 0, 0, 0}, port: 4000],


Yes i've already change the ip address in config/dev.exs :)

Are you able to hit that IP/port from your ipad browser?
